# Android, Eclipse: My app crashes on older API versions

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I have developed a simple app, using a webview. It crashes on APIs older than 11. I guess that I used some futures that are not supported on old APIs and that is why it isn't working.
Sometimes when I am changing my code in Eclipse it gives me error about this, but most of the times there's no error or warning. 
I think it's a bug in Eclipse, how should I find the parts that are causing the problem.
I won't send any code because it is a general question of mine.

Comment: Are you using ActionBar in your Activity?

Comment: Add the **support library v4** to your project, set the `minSDKVersion` in your Manifest to a lower API Level, **fix your code** accordingly.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing on devices older than `API level 11` due to `ActionBar` compatibility issues.
You will need to use support library `appcompat_v7` to make your app with `ActionBar` run on devices lower than `API level 11`.

**Here's a complete tutorial of using `appcompat_v7` library :** 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/create-dummy-app-extend.html

**Official link :**
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: what if i don't want actionbar? Currently, I am using android:Theme.Light. What can I use that has no actionbar?

Comment: Just use the **support library v4**.

Comment: Se my additional comment on your post